# VBA: Extract data using Vlookup and Offset

Tags: vba, excel, offset, vlookup

I am trying to pull data out of a large spreadsheet using VBA. 
Column A contains ID's which can repeat depending on the data stored in it.

For example i have

```
ID           Value1             Value2
1111         item1               item2
1111         item3               item4
2222         item3               item4
3333         item3               item4
3333         item3               item4
```

I enter the ID into a spreadsheet then want to use VBA to Vlookup the ID then pull the Values from column B and C into another spreadsheet.

Heres what i have

```
    Sub populate()
Dim ID As String    
Dim Value1 As String
ID = Range("D5")
   Value1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ID, Worksheets("Required").Range("A4:J1913"), 2, False)
Response = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ID, Worksheets("Required").Range("A4:J1913"), 7, False)
Worksheets("Coversheet").Range("D8") = Value1
Worksheets("Coversheet").Range("D10") = Value2
Dim Value1address As Long
Value1address = VarPtr(Value1)
Worksheets("Coversheet").Range("D15").Value = Cells(Value1address).Offset(1, 0)
End Sub
```

The code works excatly how i want, except for the last 3 lines. I am trying to get an offset from Value1 by 1 row, however it is saving as a blank, and consequently puts a blank value into Cell D15.

Can anyone help me solve this problem, or how i can easily take data from the following rows after the Vlookup?

Answer (score 1):

Use the worksheet's [MATCH function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/match-function-0600e189-9f3c-4e4f-98c1-943a0eb427ca) to return the row number to an [INDEX function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/index-function-0ee99cef-a811-4762-8cfb-a222dd31368a) while adding **+1** to it.

```
with Worksheets("Required")
    Worksheets("Coversheet").Range("D15").Value = _
      Application.Index(.Range("B4:B1913"), Application.Match(ID, .Range("A4:A1913"), 0) + 1))
End With
```

If you are finding the row, then store it and keep reusing it.

```
    Dim ID As String, val1 As String, val2 As String, val3 As String, rw As Long
    ID = Range("D5")

    With Worksheets("Required")
        If Not IsError(Application.Match(ID, .Range("A4:A1913"), 0)) Then
            rw = Application.Match(ID, .Range("A4:J1913"), 0)
            val1 = .Cells(rw + 3, 2).Value
            val2 = .Cells(rw + 3, 7).Value
            val3 = .Cells(rw + 4, 2).Value
        End If
    End With

    With Worksheets("Coversheet")
        .Range("D8") = val1
        .Range("D10") = val2
        .Range("D15") = val3
    End With
```

**[Native Worksheet formulas](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Excel-functions-by-category-5f91f4e9-7b42-46d2-9bd1-63f26a86c0eb)**

This could also be handled by standard (non-array) worksheet formula. In D8, D10 and D15 as,

```
=INDEX(Required!$B$4:$B$914, MATCH($D$5, Required!$A$4:$A$914, 0))
=INDEX(Required!$J$4:$J$914, MATCH($D$5, Required!$A$4:$A$914, 0))
=IFERROR(INDEX(Required!$B$4:$B$914, AGGREGATE(15, 6, ROW($1:$911)/(Required!$A$4:$A$914=$D$5), 2)), "n/a")
```

[image: find_second_item]

Comment: with Worksheets("Required")
    Worksheets("Coversheet").Range("D15").Value = _
      Application.Index(.Range("B4:B1913"), Application.Match(ID, .Range("A4:A1913"), 0) + 1))
End With

This will keep dumping data even if the ID has changed. For example i only want it to dump for the matched ID in D5. If i used this method for ID 2222, it would dump the next row of value, which is id 3333

Comment: Yes that's true. It is also exactly like what you were trying to accomplish with `VarPtr`. Having recognized that, I offered a secondary method that does not.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using Power Query for this task (or Get&Transform if you're on 2016 already): 
 https://www.dropbox.com/s/my59casl9y8ac3y/SO_ExtractDataUsingVLookupAndOffset.xlsx?dl=0

Code is pretty short (i.e. for Var1):

```
let
    Filter= Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="ID"]}[Content][Column1]{0},
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Tabelle1"]}[Content],
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(Source, each [ID] = Filter)
in
    #"Filtered Rows"
```

You have all formatting options for the output and the solution is fully dynamic: 
[image]